# Need help filling and cleaning up this empty space

Tags: modeling

Working on a helmet, and I need help filling this space on the rear/top side.

[image]

When I use grid fill, it sort of works, but it's recessed. I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to quickly clean this up, or fill it differently so it results in a smoother result than just Grid Fill is giving me.

[image]

[image]

This is my first post here, I apologize in advance if i've done anything outside of the SOP -- I have lurked a bit and I think i've formatted this and done enough research ahead of time. I'm just struggling to come up with something concrete for my specific situation.

Comment: you need to play with the values in the bottom left pannel when doing grid fill operation

Comment: if u provide a blend file, we can make practical reproducable solutions - else you might only get "general" hints.

Comment: *Grid Fill* cannot fill the area properly because there are only 5 vertices at the top but 7 vertices at the bottom. You need the same number of vertices for the opposite sides of the grid to be filled evenly. Add 2 more vertices (subdivide edges) to the upper curved edge and it should work.